# How to save an entity with computed column in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core with data first approach. I have generated `DbContext` and entities using scaffold command. I have a computed column in one of the table and due to this I am not being able to save the data to database. Whenever I try to save data I get following error:

> Column 'inserted.FullName' cannot be referenced in the OUTPUT clause because the column definition contains a subquery or references a function that performs user or system data access. A function is assumed by default to perform data access if it is not schemabound. Consider removing the subquery or function from the column definition or removing the column from the OUTPUT clause.

I have a User entity and the configuration as given below:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName("PK_dbo.[User]");
        entity.ToTable("User");
     
        entity.Property(e => e.FirstName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        entity.Property(e => e.FullName)
            .HasMaxLength(300)
            .HasComputedColumnSql("([dbo].[GetFullName]([FirstName],[MiddleName],[LastName]))", false);
        entity.Property(e => e.LastName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);
        entity.Property(e => e.MiddleName).HasMaxLength(100);
    });
}
```

And this method is used to save data:

```
public async ValueTask<int> Insert(TEntity entity)
{
    await _dbSet.AddAsync(entity);
    return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: It is breaking change in EF Core, try [HasTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#mitigations-2)

Comment: BTW, calling a user-defined function in a computed column is bad practice.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv what's the syntax for a user defined function using HasTrigger?

Comment: Just put HasTrigger with fake name. It will change EF Core behaviour for updating